# Can I install Linux on a external hard drive and then use it to delete the existing linux on my computer

Tags: windows, drive

The question is a bit weird but can I put linux on a external hard drive and then run my pc of that and then delete the linux partition on my laptop. I want to install windows but the booting with the disc doesn't work properly

Another Problem about this is that the windows disc is .exe, and you can't run that from linux

Comment: You can, but why not just install Windows directly? Or, boot a live CD/USB and wipe the drive before installing WIndows?

Answer (score 1):

You can even install it on a [USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). My question, however, is if you can't get Ubuntu to boot from the CD, will you be able to install Windows?

Comment: You can install Windows from a USB, that might be an option for you.

Comment: That is a good point, I think it might be the fault of ubuntu but I am not sure, I tried to install windows with WINE, but I had to make a partition which is not possible when you are running linux on that hard drive, because I wanted to delete that